# What is the best way to write and store data in python 3

Tags: python

I am trying to store data from stock market transactions I make. I want to have a file like an excel workbook, with every buy or sell price being neatly listed. I have looked at some options, including pickle, xlwt, and pandas. However, I cannot find any that can write onto a pre existing file

The information I will be storing will look like this:

DATE, TIME, STOCK_INDICATOR, BUY/SELL, PRICE

I will need the program to be able to write new rows every time a purchase is made.

Comment: Pandas is not a data storage medium, so you can scrap that straight away if it's not in memory

Comment: Use a database, sqlite would be fine if you have everything running on one machine

Comment: Do you need to store it or render/represent data, I mean, using excel has limits, I'd recommend you taking a look at psycopg and start using psql or mongo-db any database you wish to use is fine, just start using it already!

Comment: Questions that start with "what is the best way" are pretty much always off-topic on stack overflow.

Comment: I was thinking of using Pandas as a way to write to a .csv file, so then every time a new transaction is made, a new row would be added. However Pandas does not seem to be able to edit workbooks

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python update xls file", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas has a method to write data to a csv files, if this is what you mean (pandas.DataFrame.to_csv). You can specify 'write' mode, to rewrite all data, or 'append' mode, if you want to update the file with new rows.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no best way.

I would probably do it in a list-dictonary like fashion, although not sure if this would be the greates way.

something like:

```
myPurchases = [

{"date": []},
{"Time": []},...

]

// and if a new purchase is made I just would write a function which gets the list 
// and appends a new entry into the dictonarys.
```

Comment: That's a good idea, however the issue is that my program restarts itself everyday, so it won't be able to save the prior purchases. That was the original idea around writing to an excel file because then It would always have the historical information with no chance of it getting deleted

Comment: Hmmm Yeah, I guess you need to store this in a database. Unfortunately, I have not worked with one yet. Why is csv not an option?